# Can I share the two lists of downloads with Transmission and Transmission-daemon?

Tags: transmission

I just discovered transmission-daemon so I installed it to use RPC calls. I successfully added a torrent, but when I launched Transmission in Unity, there was no trace of the download.

I discovered later that I was in the web interface. So one simple question : can I share the two lists of downloads (Transmission GTK and Transmission-daemon) in both interfaces ?

Comment: See also the same question in [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/649287/is-it-possible-run-transmission-daemon-and-qt-gtk-gui-at-once-in-sync)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it seems like it's impossible : (sorry, I only found it in French)

> "Les deux applications ne se parlent pas" (i.e. "Both applications doesn't communicate") [Ubuntu-fr/transmission](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/transmission)

But, I found that Transmission GTK is already packaged with a web UI and a RPC server. So in Transmission->Edit->Preferences, go to "Web" tab, and check "Enable Web UI". Be sure to stop the daemon or the two will be on the same port and that will cause some troubles.

Now, if you go to `localhost:9091` or any port number you defined, you will see the same UI, but now with the same download list as in Transmission.

Answer (score 2):

transmission-daemon and transmission-gtk can share torrent lists by specifying the config folder on startup with the **-g** command line option.

For example to start transmission-daemon with the same settings and torrent list as transmission-gtk, you would exit transmission-gtk, then start transmission-daemon with

```
transmission-daemon -g $HOME/.config/transmission
```

You wouldn't want to do this while transmission-gtk was still running, of course.

Comment: If you want to start it when the system starts up, you can edit the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` adding the following lines:

`#!/bin/sh`
`su -c 'transmission-daemon -g /home/erik/.config/transmission' erik`

where you have to replace `erik` by your username of course. Don’t forget to make this file executable with `sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/rc.local`.